# Is this implementation of a general semaphore with binary semaphores correct?

Tags: concurrency, semaphore, binary-semaphore

Prove or Disprove the correctness of the following semaphore.

[image: semaphore in question]

Here are my thoughts on this.
Well, if someone implements it so wait runs first before signal, there will be a deadlock. The program will call wait, decrement count, enter the count < 0 condition and wait at gate. Because it is waiting at gate, it cannot proceed to the signal that is right after the wait. So in that case, this might imply that the semaphore is incorrect.

However, if we assume that two processes are running, one running wait first and the other running signal first, then if the first process run waits and blocks at wait(gate), then the other process can run signal and release the process that was blocked. Thus, continuing on this scheme would make the algorithm valid and not result in a dead lock.

Comment: At least tell me why you down voted this. I assume it works because if it runs signal first then it will work fine without dead locking.

Comment: This is a rather serious inquiry.

Comment: Then add your assumptions and speculations into your question post, for show your efforts. Currently the question looks like you want us to make your homework for you.

Comment: Sorry, I should've added my thoughts on this

Answer (score 0):

Given implementation follows these principles:

1. Binary semaphore `S` protect `count` variable from concurrent access.
2. If non-negative, `count` reflect number of free resources for general semaphore. Otherwise, absolute value of `count` reflect number of threads which wait (`p5`) or **ready-to-wait** (between `p4` and `p5`) on binary semaphore `gate`.
3. Every `signal()` call increments `count` and, if its *previous* value is negative, signals binary semaphore `gate`.

But, because of possibility of **ready-to-wait** state, **given implementation is incorrect**:

Assume `thread#1` calls `wait()`, and currently is in *ready-to-wait* state. Assume another `thread#2` also calls `wait()`, and currently is in *ready-to-wait* state too.

Assume `thread#3` calls `signal()` at this moment. Because count is negative (-2), the thread performs all operations including  `p10` (`signal(gate)`). Because `gate` is not waited at the moment, it becomes in *free* state.

Assume another `thread#4` calls `signal()` at this moment. Because `count` is still negative (-1), the thread also performs all operations including `p10`. But now `gate` is already in *free* state. So, `signal(gate)` is *no-op* here, and we have *missed* signal event: only one of `thread#1` and `thread#2` will continue after executing `p5` (`wait(gate)`). Other thread **will wait forever**.

Without possibility of *ready-to-wait* state (that is `signal(S)` and `wait(gate)` would be executed *atomically*) implementation would be OK.